# How to compare two tables data and store it another table in laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, join

Hi i am working on reset password with the help of admin section in my website but i am facing an issue now .actually i dont know how to compare two table with each other and if they match then how to store this request to another table. Here is schema of both table. User Table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Forget password request Table

```
 Schema::create('Forgot_Passwords', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
         });
```

I have to match email,weight and height of both tables with each other .

Comment: what columns would you like to compare with?

Comment: Why are you storing weight and height in `forgot_passwords`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your entering an email.

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
$forgotPassword = ForgotPassword::where('email', $email)->first();

$if(($user->email == $forgotPassword->email) and ($user->weight == $forgotPassword->weight) and ($user->height == $forgotPassword->height)  { 
   // some insert code here
}
```

Hope this gives you and idea.